# Why am I getting a weird answer while trying to reverse elements of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java programming. So i tried to reverse the elements of an array using the code shown in the image. But I am getting a completely different kind of answer. Please help me out!
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQCyJ.jpg

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr = {1,3,4,6};
        int[] arr2 = new int[4];
        for (int k = 0; k<4; k++){
            arr2[4-(k+1)] = arr[k];
        }
        System.out.println(arr2);
        in.close();
    }
```

}

Comment: We don't look at pictures of code. Code is text. paste the code here.

Comment: Try: ```System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));```

Comment: okay, sorry. I pasted the code

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your logic is correct, however, you aren't printing arr2 correctly. Use another for-loop.